# How to kill a process started by android am

Tags: android, adb

I use the following command to start playing a movie on my android device:

```
adb shell am start -d file:///sdcard/fff.wvm -t video/3gp -a android.intent.action.VIEW
```

I want to stop (kill) the process before it finishes. Does anyone know the process name "am start" command create? I used ps to get the running processes in the background, but there is a lot, and it is hard to tell which one is.

Comment: This would likely depend on the Android version and installed apps, but it's going to be something related to media or video.  There's a less than reliable API call for determining the top Activity which could help you.  Or if you actually have the ability to kill the process, perhaps it is because you are root, at which point you can troll the the /proc directory as lsof on a desktop linux does and figure out who has the destination file open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the package being started, use:

```
adb shell am force-stop <PACKAGE>
```

For me `com.android.gallery` worked pretty fine, however this depends on the installed app and preferred apps, of course. Going i.e. pushing *Back* might end the playback - it least it worked with the system player:

```
adb shell input keyevent 4
```

Appending the command ...

```
adb shell am kill-all
```

... should kill the process afterwards.

Comment: On my device, I have this one: com.android.gallery3d